# If column A matches column C input column D into column B

Tags: excel

I have a sales tracking sheet where column A contains the profit margin of a particular job (i.e.33%), Column C is the profit margin range(i.e. 31-40%), and Column D is the corresponding commission to that specific range identified in Column C (i.e. 31-40% = 3% commission).

What I want is a formula that will automatically pull the Commission from Column D into Column B when I enter the profit margin of that particular job in Column A.

Any ideas/does that make sense?

Comment: try using some formulas containing 'IF' statements. Also I think you might be in the wrong place here at stackoveflow for this...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values in column A are formatted as percentage, you could use something like this:

```
=INDEX(D$1:D$10,MATCH(A1*100,1*LEFT(C$1:C$10,FIND("-",C$1:C$10)-1),1))
```

And press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering the formula instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone.

This will return a value from range `D$1:D$10` where the value from `A1` (multiplied by 100 to remove the decimals) is less than the lower bound of the margin range in range `C$1:C$10`.

Change the ranges accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In B1, put:

```
=IF(A1=C1,D1,0)
```

You can obviously change row numbers to work as needed.

The IF statement has 3 parts, the condition:

=IF(A1=C1,

Here I'm testing to see if the expression is TRUE or FALSE.  I can do anything I want here, as long as it evaluates to either a True or False condition.

Next, we specify the "True" result, and the "false" result, which are, respectively, what happens when those conditions are met.  For the TRUE condition, we just want to use the value in cell D:

```
D1,
```

For the FALSE condition, I don't know what you want, so I just put in a 0.

```
0)
```

Note that all 3 parts of the IF statement are separated by commas - play around, you can do a LOT of different things!

EDIT:  Just noticed that column C is a range, while A is a singular value.  You're going to need to do something like @Jerry did with parsing out the range string.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that columns A and B will be indefinitely long just based on how much data is collected, whereas columns C and D are just a reference table with 10 rows each for the 10 ranges (0 - 10%, 11 - 20%, 21 - 30%, etc.). Is this correct?

As an alternative to storing the profit margin range and corresponding commission in columns C and D as you now do, you could incorporate them directly into an IF statement that you use in column B. For example if 91-100% corresponds to 8% commission, 81-90% is 7% commission and so on, then you could insert this formula:

```
=IF(A2>90,0.08,IF(A2>80,0.07,IF(A2>70,0.06,IF(A2>60,0.05, ...
```

The advantage to this compared to using and index-match combination which references numbers extracted from the text ("11-20%"), is that you don't run the risk of losing data when the text ranges are altered in some way. (I.e. userproof.)

Comment: I like this idea and it works well, got 1 other question you may be able to assist with.

Comment: Certainly. What is your other question? And if the above answer is satisfactory then you can check it off as correct.